# android eclipse problem detecting String null

Tags: android, string, eclipse

Hello I have to do a job for school Programming an Android Application with Eclipse and I had a problem, In this application you have to enter the EDITTEXT `editName`, `editCode`, `editGenero`and `editPrice` text strings and int. When the button "abonar" is pressed if these are equal to 0 or null, it is not must activate the calculation of the amount to be paid and the error must be reported, the issue is that when I test the application and do not enter any value the application stops working, it works correctly if I put a 0, so I have tried a boolean method, using the commands .`length () == 0`, `isEmpty ()` which seems not to work in this version of eclipse and `String == null` but still does not work, also does not eclipse inform me of any errors in the code, so I respectfully request help from someone to tell me where the fault is or to provide me with some way to do it without the application exploding.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     private EditText etc,etn,etg,etp,eti;
     private RadioButton rc,rt;
     private CheckBox checkBox1;
     String codigoS;
     String nombre;
     String generoS;
     String precioS;
     int codigo;
     int genero;
     float precio=0;
     float precioTotal=0;
     float des=0;
 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
     etc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCodigo);
     etn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNombre);
     etg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editGenero);
     etp=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPrecio);
     eti=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editImporte);
     rc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonContado);
     rt=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonTarjeta);
     checkBox1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);   
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}
public boolean validar(){
    boolean retorno=true;
     
    codigoS=etc.getText().toString();
    nombre=etn.getText().toString();
    generoS=etg.getText().toString();
    precioS=etp.getText().toString();
    codigo=Integer.parseInt(codigoS);
    genero=Integer.parseInt(generoS);
    precio=Float.parseFloat(precioS);
    
    if(codigoS.length()==0||codigo==0){
        etc.setError("Se requiere un codigo");
        retorno=false;
    }
    if(nombre.length()==0){
        etn.setError("Se requiere un nombre");
        retorno=false;
    }
    if(generoS.length()==0||genero==0){ 
        etg.setError("Se requiere un genero");
        retorno=false;
}
    if(precioS.length()==0||precio==0){ 
        etp.setError("Se requiere un precio");
        retorno=false;
    }
    return retorno;
}

public void abonar (View view){
     
    Intent i = new Intent(this,AbonarImporte .class );

if(validar())   {
    if(rc.isChecked()==(true)){
        des=(precio/10);
        precioTotal=precio-des;
    }
    if(rt.isChecked()==(true)){
        des=(precio/10)*2;
        precioTotal=precio+des;  
    }
    if(checkBox1.isChecked()==(true)){
        int pago=100;
        precioTotal=precioTotal+pago;   
    }
    
    eti.setText(String.valueOf("$ "+precioTotal));
    i.putExtra("Nombre",nombre);
    i.putExtra("Precio",precioTotal);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

Comment: 1. You might wants to separate your text into a paragraph/sections to make it more cleaner
2. The snippet code attached might be better to formatting it accordingly so it's easier to read as well
3. To reduce cluttered information, instead of copy-paste the whole activity class, imho, the `abonar` & `validar` function was the highlighted snippet code cmiiw

Answer (score 0):

You should check these strings whether are blanks(eg. `" "`) or not

Comment: you mean something like this?                                                                                                        
                                                                                           
     if(codigoS.length()==""||codigo==0){
        etc.setError("Se requiere un codigo");
        retorno=false;

Comment: You can do it like this:  
        EditText editText = binding.editTextTextPersonName;
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(editText.getText())) {
            xx.setError("xxxx");
            return false;
        }

StringUtils is from apache commons lang:
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'